# how to center everything in my blog

Tags: meta-tags

i just recently changed my blog templates.the everything start to mess up!the blog feeds and the text,picture,everything is just not in the right place.its in the opposite place.what should be in the left side is in the right side and the blog feed is n the other side of the page.what should i do to make all things right again and be in the normal condition again?please,help me.

Comment: can you send us a link to your site? it'd be very helpful.

Comment: Seems like you have 2 containers and you're floating one to the left (or right) and not the other. This might cause the floating container to appear on the 'other' side. But very hard to say without knowing what actually you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the float:left for the both the blocks so that they will be placed side by side one after the other. OR revert the blog template files back and go one by one.